# Can't access app.set variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a web app with expressjs at the moment.

I want to pass the port that the app is running on from the `callingScript` to the `module`:

## `callingScript.js`

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./module');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

// it serves to the correct port, so the problem is passing it to module.js
app.listen(port);
```

## `module.js`

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// this always logs `undefined`
console.log(app.get('port'));

module.exports = app;
```

---

If I run the above application I want to see results like this:

```
$ node callingScript.js
3000
$ PORT=8080 bash -c 'node callingScript.js'
8080
```

but instead it prints `undefined` every time.

It looks like module.js isn't being passed the variable from its calling script.

How can I pass the port between the two?

Comment: You're calling `.get()` before you're calling `.set()`.

Comment: @robertklep but how do I pass the port then?

Comment: Declare `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;` in the top of `callingScript.js` module, before any `require`.

Answer (score 0):

You're logging at the wrong time. *First* your `module.js` runs, *then* your `callingScript.js` runs. The `console.log` with `app.get` is in your `module.js`, which runs *before* the `app.set` in `callingScript.js`.

---

If you want to do something with the configured port in code in `module.js`, just ensure you call that code after setting the port. For instance, here we export an object with both `app` and `foo`, where `foo` is a function:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

module.exports = {
    app,
    foo: function() {
        console.log("The port is " + app.get("port"));
    }
};
```

then calling it:

```
const http = require('http');
const m = require('./module');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

m.app.set('port', port);
m.foo(); // <====

const server = http.createServer(m.app);

// it serves to the correct port, so the problem is passing it to module.js
m.app.listen(port);
```

That said, it sounds like you might want to make your module expose a function that accepts a port and returns an `app` configured to use that port (along with anything else that needs to know what the port is).

Comment: So how do I fix this and pass the `port` as I'd like to?

Comment: @minseong: What makes you think you aren't? Since you're setting the port before calling `createServer`, it will listen on the port you've set. If you had code in `module.js` that you called *after* calling `app.set`, and that code used `app.get`, it would see the value you set.

Comment: Any code in `module.js` that runs *after* the `app.set` will see the updated value in `app.get`.

Comment: @minseong: You expose a function that you call after, hook up a handler for some event that occurs after, or a dozen other things.

Comment: @minseong: I've added one of the ways you could do it to the answer, but you have a lot of options.

Comment: My actual application is much much larger than this. Do i have to put _all_ the code into foo()?

Comment: @minseong: The primary thing here isn't location, it's timing. So any code responding to events that occur after the call to `app.set` in the calling script can be anywhere in `module.js` you want. Code which may run prior to the `app.set` will need to be somewhere where the calling script can trigger it when `app.set` has been done. FWIW, it seems odd to me that `module.js` would create `app` but the caller would call `listen`, as opposed to the caller creating it, setting it up, and passing it to something in `module.js` that does whatever the module does.